# Invalid webhook url specified Error in Telegram bot

Tags: python, webhooks, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, ngrok

I am trying to make a simple telegram echo bot and use webhooks in it (ngrok). I am getting this error, I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I also tried releasing port 8443, but still nothing.

The error I am getting (The URL is correct, I copied it directly from running ngrok terminal):

```
(myvenv) (base) akriti@hp:~/Desktop/Get-Informed$ python bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 61, in <module>
    bot.set_webhook("http://c026-122-161-51-216.ngrok.io" + TOKEN)
  File "/home/akriti/Desktop/Get-Informed/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 130, in decorator
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/akriti/Desktop/Get-Informed/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 2965, in set_webhook
    result = self._post('setWebhook', data, timeout=timeout, api_kwargs=api_kwargs)
  File "/home/akriti/Desktop/Get-Informed/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 295, in _post
    return self.request.post(
  File "/home/akriti/Desktop/Get-Informed/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 361, in post
    result = self._request_wrapper(
  File "/home/akriti/Desktop/Get-Informed/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/utils/request.py", line 279, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Invalid webhook url specified
```

Following is my code:

```
import logging 
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, Dispatcher


# enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

TOKEN = "213181**********"

# create Flask app object
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello!"

# create view to handle webhooks
@app.route(f'/{TOKEN}', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    """webhook view which receives updates from telegram"""
    # create update object from json-format request data
    update = Update.de_json(request.get_json(), bot)
    # process update
    dp.process_update(update)
    return "ok"


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    print(update)
    author = update.message.from_user.first_name
    # msg = update.message.text
    reply = "Hi! {}".format(author)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text=reply)
     

def _help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    help_txt = "Hey! This is a help text."
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text=help_txt)


def echo_text(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    reply = update.message.text
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text=reply)
    

def echo_sticker(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_sticker(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, sticker=update.message.sticker.file_id)


def error(update, context):
    logger.error("Update '%s' caused error '%s'", update, update.error)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create telegram bot object
    bot = Bot(TOKEN)
    # set webhook for telegram bot 
    bot.set_webhook("http://c026-122-161-51-216.ngrok.io" + TOKEN)

    dp = Dispatcher(bot, None)
    # add handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", _help))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo_text))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sticker, echo_sticker))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    app.run(port=8443)
```

Comment: YOu left your **private** bot token in your code. People might abuse it! You should revoke it!

Comment: Yes, I edited it

Comment: It's still visible in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70022821/revisions) so you should ask @BotFather for new one

Comment: Oh okay, I'll change it then. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"http://c026-122-161-51-216.ngrok.io" + TOKEN` will result in `"http://c026-122-161-51-216.ngrok.ioTOKEN"`, which is not a valid URL. you'll probably want to use `"http://c026-122-161-51-216.ngrok.io/" + TOKEN` with a slash

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a lifesaver!!